# How to remove URL parameters from Google Analytics reports

Tags: google-analytics

My Google Analytics record pages with dynamic parameters. URL looks like:

/iframe/dashboard/214301/customercare/cc
/iframe/dashboard/842904/customercare/serviska-fb
/module/customercare/serviska-fb/842904

The problem is that site content report cannot merge these URLs as an access to the same page `/customercare`.

How can I solve it?

I know that I can add a custom filter in the account settings, but how to setup regular expression?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search and Replace Filters supports regular expressions so you might have a filter like:

```
Search string: /customercare(\/.*)
Replace string: /customercare
```

where `(\/.*)` is a part of a regular expression matching all the characters following `/customercare`